# VS 2017 - need to fix `cw` code snippet output

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, code-snippets

At some point in VS 2017 (most probably after an update to version 15.8.7) the `cw` code snippet which usually produced `Console.WriteLine();` has began to produce `System.Console.WriteLine();`.

Surprisingly this behavior is not constant - it works as expected in old projects with the same VS version.

I've tried to remove `.vs` folder and it didn't help.

Here is the content of **cw.snippet** file from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#\cw.snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>cw</Title>
            <Shortcut>cw</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for Console.WriteLine</Description>
            <Author>Microsoft Corporation</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal Editable="false">
                    <ID>SystemConsole</ID>
                    <Function>SimpleTypeName(global::System.Console)</Function>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[$SystemConsole$.WriteLine($end$);]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Is there a way to fix `cw` snippet so it always produces `Console.WriteLine();`?

Comment: In the files where it adds `System.Console.WriteLine` do you have a `using System;` there? And vice versa: where it doesn't - do you have it there?

Comment: @Fildor you are right. That is just how it works, and should work. It has always done that.

Comment: For those where I have `System.Cosole.WriteLine` it produces the same output for files that have `using System;` and for those who don't and `using System;` is not added. For those where it doesn't, it works perfect for having `using System;` or adding it automatically with `cw`.

Answer (score 4):

For me, I ended up just editing the snippet itself.  I'm sure I will need to do this every time there is an update and I'm not sure of a better permanent fix outside of creating a user-defined snippet.

My quick and dirty fix was to edit the file...

> %USERPROFILE%.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\snippets\csharp.json

Then look for the following section (found mine around line 53)...

```
"Console.WriteLine": {
    "prefix": "cw",
    "body": [
        "System.Console.WriteLine($0);"
    ],
    "description": "Console.WriteLine"
},
```

Then just change...

```
"System.Console.WriteLine($0);"
```

To...

```
"Console.WriteLine($0);"
```

Save, then restart VSCode and test the `cw` snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In fact, it was a VS related issue, not VSCode, still I find this information very helpful and valuable.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell the snippet if the using statement for system is not already on the page to add it. Include the following **after** the open tag `<snippet>` and **before** opening `<declarations>` tag.

```
<Imports>
    <Import>
        <Namespace>System</Namespace>
    </Import>
</Imports>
```

For Reference to add more (in this case it isn't needed but you may in the future) imports you will need to make separate tag pairs (as below).

```
<Import>
    <Namespace></Namespace>
</Import>
```

Comment: Thanks, that didn't help either. But with your help I am now sure that it's a VS bug since the `cw.snippet` is not loaded properly.